# Error: unexpected '}' in "}

Tags: r, trigonometry

I am trying to build a function to calculate the magnitude and direction 
of vector operation. In order to solve the problem that inverse trig function is restricted within the domain of pi/2 and -pi/2, I need to add 2pi to the e if e is less than 0. But I encounter the "Error: unexpected '}' in "}" once I added the if else line. Would anyone be able to explain to me why?

```
vectorMD <- function(x){
    c=x[1:2]-x[3:4]
    mt  <- function(x) {round(sqrt(sum(x^2)),1)}
    d <- round(mt(c),1)
    e <- round(atan(c[2]/c[1]),1)
if(e < 0){e <- e+2*2pi
    return(e)} 
paste("magnitude =",d,"direction =",e)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 2pi in if condition you have to give as 2*pi since pi is already a value like 3.14 you can't specify it as 2pi which is like 23.14 so you have to specify it has 2*pi which is like 2*3.14

**The code:**

```
vectorMD <- function(x){
    c=x[1:2]-x[3:4]
    mt  <- function(x) {round(sqrt(sum(x^2)),1)}
    d <- round(mt(c),1)
    e <- round(atan(c[2]/c[1]),1)
    if(e < 0){e <- e+2*2*pi
        return(e)} 
    paste("magnitude =",d,"direction =",e)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put function "mt" outside of function "vector".

```
mt  <- function(x) 
{
    round(sqrt(sum(x^2)),1)
}

vectorMD <- function(x)
{
    c=x[1:2]-x[3:4]

    d <- round(mt(c),1)
    e <- round(atan(c[2]/c[1]),1)

    if(e < 0)
    {
        e <- e+2*2pi
        return(e)
    }

    paste("magnitude =",d,"direction =",e)
}
```

Comment: That ain't the problem @nico you have to specify 2pi as 2*pi